# Google Chrome completely disappeared from my machine - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, google-chrome

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and have had Google Chrome installed for some time now. It's the only browser I use and was in the sidebar on my desktop. Just minutes ago, I temporarily changed my IP using `ifconfig` to something that broke my internet connection. So I restarted my machine, and come back to an Ubuntu completely devoid of Google Chrome. I can't find a single trace of Chrome on my machine and have no idea what would've happened. Does anyone have a clue as to why this might have occurred? I'm absolutely bewildered.

`whereis google-chrome` and `which google-chrome` return no results, it does not appear in searches, nothing related in trash, etc

Comment: Same thing happened to me

Comment: @AnnaIraHurnaus - same thing happened to me but chromium reappeared 20 minutes later. Chrome is a "snap" and they update themselves. It must have taken a long time this morning.

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig would not delete installed programs. You may have removed it from the sidebar by accident but "whereis" and "which" should still have found it unless your path is messed up.

What does "echo $PATH" show?